# How does vim implementation draws (prints) on screen over last printed buffer?

Tags: vim

How is vim implemented, is just ''runs clear command on every redraw'' or some sort of ''draw on screen with ABCD XYZ command''?

Comment: [TUI: Text user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterminal%5D+text+user+interface

Answer (score 0):

Vim has 2 commands for redrawing parts of the interface, there is `redraw` for updating the screen, and `:redrawstatus` for redrawing the status line in the current window.

I believe the way that both of these work is by just going over the screen, or status bar, replacing character it gets to with what needs to be in there. With the `redraw` command you can also add `!` to the end to make it clear the screen before redrawing. And adding `!` to `:redrawstatus` will just make it redraw all status bars.